# Issue printing an array of images in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, iteration, gallery

I'm doing a simple gallery using an array of images:

```
var gallery_pictures = [
    { name:'01.jpg', alt:'01'},
    { name:'02.jpg', alt:'01'},
    { name:'03.jpg', alt:'01'},
    { name:'04.jpg', alt:'01'},
    { name:'05.jpg', alt:'01'}
];
```

Inside this container:

```
<div style="width:1000px; margin: 0 auto;" id="gallery">

</div>
```

And using a function that store the text in a variable using a map:

```
var gallery = gallery_pictures.map(function gallery(foto, index, array) {
    pictures = '<div style="width:190px;margin-right: 10px; float:left;"><img width="200" src="'+foto.name+'" alt="'+foto.alt+'" "></div>'
    return pictures;
});
```

Then I print it in my div using innerHTML:

```
imageGallery.innerHTML=gallery;
```

The issue I have is that somehow there is a coma "," being printed between each picture. Here the code result in chrome:

[image: like in the screenshoot]

And here how it looks in the screen:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat array in a way there is no commas in it.

```
var gallery = "";
gallery_pictures.forEach(function(foto){
    var pictures = '<div style="width:190px;margin-right: 10px; float:left;"><img width="200" src="'+foto.name+'" alt="'+foto.alt+'" "></div>';
    gallery += pictures;
});
imageGallery.innerHTML = gallery;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is each or a normal for loop.

You have printed an array as html. That is the reason they appear like array element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You are getting back an array with the elements inside. That is the reason you seeing commas.